# MySQL insert in table if ANY exists

Tags: mysql

I have a table `RolePermissions` that looks like this:

| id | RoleID | PermissionID | CompanyID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1278 | 57 | 279 | 33 |
| 1279 | 57 | 280 | 33 |
| 1280 | 57 | 281 | 33 |
| ... |  |  |  |

I need to run a backfill query for a new `PermissionID` and I need to run the backfill for any `RoleId` that currently exists in this table. The backfill rule is:

`For any given RoleID, if the table contains any of the 3 PermissionIDs (279, 280, 281) then a new row must be added to the table. If no row for the given RoleID with PermissionID IN (279, 280, 281) no row should be inserted`

This would be straightforward to me using a language like Python for the migration but I can only use plain SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `WHERE PermissionID IN (279, 280, 281)` to test if any of those permissions already exist for a `roleID`.

Then use that in a `SELECT` query that supplies the rows for the new permission.

```
INSERT INTO RolePermissions (RoleID, PermissionID, CompanyID)
SELECT DISTINCT RolePermissions.RoleID, @new_PermissionID, RolePermissions.CompanyID
FROM RolePermissions 
WHERE PermissionID IN (279, 280, 281)
```

Answer (score 1):

For example, do it directly:

```
INSERT INTO RolePermissions (RoleID, PermissionID, CompanyID)
SELECT DISTINCT RolePermissions.RoleID, @new_PermissionID, RolePermissions.CompanyID
FROM RolePermissions 
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
               FROM RolePermissions rp
               WHERE RolePermissions.RoleID = rp.RoleID
                 AND RolePermissions.CompanyID = rp.CompanyID
                 AND rp.PermissionID = 279)
  AND EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
               FROM RolePermissions rp
               WHERE RolePermissions.RoleID = rp.RoleID
                 AND RolePermissions.CompanyID = rp.CompanyID
                 AND rp.PermissionID = 280)
  AND EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
               FROM RolePermissions rp
               WHERE RolePermissions.RoleID = rp.RoleID
                 AND RolePermissions.CompanyID = rp.CompanyID
                 AND rp.PermissionID = 281)
```